# My for loop isnt being read on my scraper of gamestop

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I cant get his for loop to be read and take the listing of items it just prints nothing at all and skips the whole loop 
    import requests
    import re
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    maxPages = 10
    keyword = "ps4"
    costMax = 0
    costMin = 0

```
def tradeSpiderGS(maxPages):
    page = 1
    while page <= maxPages:
        print(page)
        #creating url for soup
        if page <= 1:
        url = 'https://www.gamestop.com/browse?nav=16k-3-'+ keyword 
        +',28zu0'
        else:
            url = 'https://www.gamestop.com/browse?nav=16k-3-' + keyword + 
            ',2b'+ 
        str(page *12) + ',28zu0'
        #creating soup object
        srcCode = requests.get(url)
        plainTxt = srcCode.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plainTxt,"html.parser")

        #this for loop is not being read supposed to grab links on gs website
        for links in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'ats-product-title-lnk'}):
            href = links.get('href')
            trueHref = 'https://www.gamestop.com/' + href
            print(trueHref)
        page += 1

tradeSpiderGS(maxPages)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why Doesn't the Loop Run?**

The loop doesn't run because `soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'ats-product-title-lnk'})` is `[]` (there aren't any `a` with that class).

The reason there aren't any `a` with that class is that `GameStop` doesn't let you access the `/browse` pages unless you've been to a normal page first. You can confirm this by opening one of the urls in a web browser in incognito mode:

[image]

**Workarounds:**

You can use a different scraping mechanism like [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) in python to work around this. You might also be able to copy headers from a web browser request into the `request.get` call, although I wasn't able to get this to work.

Comment: interestingly enough, I did not receive a 'Access Denied' page when accessing the same url via incognito mode.